# LINQ/lambda: How can I query a DB table based on information from another table? (many to many relationship)

Tags: c#, database, linq, lambda, many-to-many

I have a database scheme with 3 tables. One for requisitions, one for hospitals, and one joining the two (many-to-many relationship).

I'd like to list all requisitions in the database that are linked to a selected hospital.

This is what I have so far:

```
var valgtSykehus = Db.Sykehus.Where(n => n.Navn == sykehus).Single(); //this gives me a variable with my current hospital. I want to list all requistions that contains this.

var Rekvisisjoner = Db.Rekvisisjoner
                    .Where(r => r.Arkivert == true) //get only archived requsitions
                    .Include(p1 => p1.Sykehus) //include hospitals
                    .ToList() //this generates a list of -all- requisitions with the hospitals they are attached to.
                    .Where(x => x.Created > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)) /only go 3 years back
                    .Where(x => x.Sykehus.Contains(valgtSykehus)); //here is the problem. I want to discard all requisitions that does NOT contain the hospital in the valgtSykehus variable
```

Anyway, this gives me zero requistions, but if I skip the last line, I get *all* archived requistions.

Answer (score 1):

`x.Sykehus.Contains(valgtSykehus)` executes in LINQ to Objects context (due to the intermediate `ToList` call) and most likely uses reference equality, which normally should work as soon as you use tracking queries.

Still, it's safer and also more efficient to do the whole thing with a single db query using `Any` condition with primitive key. Something like this:

```
var Rekvisisjoner = Db.Rekvisisjoner
    .Include(r => r.Sykehus) //include hospitals
    .Where(r => r.Arkivert == true) //get only archived requsitions the hospitals they are attached to.
    .Where(r => r.Created > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)) /only go 3 years back
    .Where(r => r.Sykehus.Any(s => s.Navn == sykehus));
```

If there is an issues with using `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)` inside the query, just put into variable outside of the query and use it inside.

```
var minDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3);
var Rekvisisjoner =
   // ...
   .Where(r => r.Created > minDate)
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may lie in the implementation of `Contains`. `Contains` has to check equality somehow. Anyway, if your `valgtSykehus` object is logically contained in `x.Sykehus` (i.e. has the same data), but not exactly the same object (i.e. the same reference), it's possible that `Contains` fails to find it, due to the default implementation of `==` in reference types (`==` is true, if the objects are exactly the same reference, `false` otherwise, even though all the data is the same).

You could try the following:

```
var Rekvisisjoner = Db.Rekvisisjoner
                    .Where(r => r.Arkivert == true)
                    .Include(p1 => p1.Sykehus)
                    .ToList() 
                    .Where(x => x.Created > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)) 
                    .Where(x => x.Sykehus.Any(sh => sh.Id == valgtSykehus.Id));
```

If `Id` (or whatever your ID property is named) is a value field (most likely) this will return `true` whenever the ID of an `Sykehus` matches the ID of `valgtSykehus`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my.
I just realised that none of the archived requisitions contains any connections to the hospitals, as they apparently are removed one-by-one when the requisition is processed in the program.

I figured this out while trying to reverse the query, so thanks for that tip.